# Android ViewModel for shop/shoppingcart functionality

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-viewmodel

I'm currently trying to make a shop app with a shopping cart. When the user taps an item in the shop, it takes them to a detail fragment of the product, with the option of adding it to the cart. The cart is only accessible from the shop fragment.

I'm currently struggling to figure out how to pass the item from the detail fragment to the shopping cart using MVVM.
I tried creating a Model containing an empty list that gets filled with [name, amount] pairs when the user clicks the order button. However this turned out to be quite the hassle (not knowing where to instantiate it, lifecycle issues, ...)

In short this is what I'm trying to do

```
                select item
+-----------+                   +------------+
|           | +-------------->  |            |
| Shop      |                   | ItemDetail |
|           |                   |            |
|           |                   |            |
|           |                   |            |
|           |                   |            |
|           |   order item      |            |
|           | <-------------+   |            |
+----+------+                   +------------+
     |
     |add ordered item to cart
     |
     |
     |
     v
 +---+------+
 |          |
 |          |
 | Cart     |
 |          |
 |          |
 |          |
 |          |
 +----------+
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Can you please revise your question with actual questions?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating